# Password Protected Alert

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make it so that you have to write a password to see an alert. I am no JavaScript expert so I don't how to make it. But in python it would look something like this:

```
password = "123"
input = input("What is the password?")
if password == input:
  alert("The password was right!")
else:
  alert("Wrong password!")
```

Can you also "activate" this script via a "anchor" tag and "href"?

Sorry if this was badly explained, if you have any questions, please post them below.

Comment: There would be no point. The password, as well as the content you're trying to protect, would be visible in your client-side code. If you want to do that in a somewhat secure way, you'd have to send the password to a server for verification.

Comment: or at least compare a hash.

Comment: I know, but is it still possible to do this?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible as demonstrated in the answer below. Possible, but pointless.

Comment: This is so close to working that I have to wonder how much effort you put into this before asking.

Comment: Please, let us not talk about that. I am a noob. I will say that. I am also very new to coding. I am 15 years old, and I started with html, css and JS for 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prompt` to capture user input. Like so:

```js
function onClick() {
  const password = "123"
  const input = prompt("What is the password?")

  if (input === password) {
    alert("The password was right!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong password!");
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="onClick();">TEST ANCHOR</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the script I am looking for, but how do I link the "anchor" and "href" to this code?

Comment: Thank you so much!